# Tools for insufficient authentication

Tags: automated-testing, tools, test-automation-framework

I must test a website for insufficient authentication. Use case:

- I go to website which I'll testing.
- Log in as admin(user with the highest permissions/privileges)
- Run some tool.
- Tool has login and password for regular user which doesnt has
  permissions that admin has.
- Tool intercepts requests that I call manually as admin via browser
- Then tool remove cookies from request which it intercepts and
  substitutes it with credentials for regular user
- Then tool passes request but with cookies of regular user and shows
  response of request in the other browser or somewhere else.

Im looking this kind of tool. Can anyone recommend me one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe Fiddler could be used to assist in the scenario you provided.
Check it out at http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: The fiddler API is nice too if you want to automate this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Watir](http://watir.com/). Both automate browsers. You can create a script that will take username and password as arguments. The script does what needs to be done as admin and regular user.